# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'NativeModules.UIManager.RCTVideo.Constants')

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

How to integrate a Video player? I tried to follow the instructions from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video#todos, but it throws an error "undefined is not an object" (evaluating 'NativeModules.UIManager.RCTVideo.Constants')

Comment: Did you run rnpm link?

Comment: Hi Vijay, i tried now, but rnpm link failed for me...

Comment: even i did the whole process again... including rnpm linking.. linking was successful but same error

Comment: there's an [open issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/284) you'll find interesting

Comment: Finally it worked for me after several times of repeating the document proceedure.. interestingly video got hided by alignItems("center") style for the parent container.. so nothing visible to me. then i tried to remove the style one by one and found the culprit "alignItems"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing react-native-video with pods :

1) install pods

2) add this to your podfile is ios folder of your project :

```
pod 'react-native-video', path: '../node_modules/react-native-video'
```

3) launch pod install

4) maybe delete the "-obj" in the "target support files" of file "pods". You can find it by opening your xcworkspace file in xcode.

5) rerun your project